# Sending POST request with body in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, axios

I want to send a post request with the body in Axios. here is the function I wrote and here the API will work if it only has a header. But in the case for APIs that need a body, it's not working. (Error since API body is not properly received in the server.). Is this the proper way to do this.

```
const post = (endPoint = '', header = {}, body = {}) => {
       return axios({method: 'POST', url: `${urls.apiBaseUrl}/${endPoint}/?tenant_id=3`, headers: header, body: body})
}
```

Comment: Try to pass the body before the header.
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

axios({method: 'POST', url: `${urls.apiBaseUrl}/${endPoint}/?tenant_id=3`, body: body, headers: header})

Comment: thnku for the response, But still it doesn't work.

Comment: FYI in modern JavaScript you don't write `body: body` - you simply write `body`. So, given that the API for `axios` requires the parameter to be named `data`, you could simply rename the parameter to your `post` function from `body` to `data`, and then pass `data` to the `axios` method.

Comment: @jarmod Got it! Thank you for the information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper way to do this.
What you have to do is just pass the body as data. (Not body)

```
const post = (endPoint = '', header = {}, body = {}) => {
        return axios({method: 'POST', url: `${urls.apiBaseUrl}/${endPoint}/?tenant_id=3`, headers: header, data: body})
}
```

Note: Answered by the original author. The author has been added this answer into the question itself, so reformatted the question and posted this answer here.